# How to remove data-0 attribute from div?

Tags: html, jquery, web-deployment

I have a html code like below.

```
<div id="asa" class="bg"
    data-0="transform:scale(1, 1); opacity:1"
    data-1000="transform:scale(2, 1); opacity:0.5"
    data-5000="transform:scale(2, 2); opacity:1">   

    //Some Code

</div>
```

I want to remove 'data-1000' attribute from the div or change 'data-1000' into 'data-2500'. How can I do it? I tried $('#asa').removeAttr('data-1000'); and many more. But they did not work.

Comment: I'm using 'skrollr.min.js' in my site. In case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Try this code first:

```
document.getElementById('home_bg1').removeAttribute('data-1000');
```

---

**Option 2:** If the first code doesn't work for you ... try this one

*If the element you want to edit is loaded by another script, it is necessary for the editing script to wait. This code waits for an item with the ID `#home_bg1` to appear and then executes*

```js
var checkEx = setInterval(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('home_bg1');
    if (el) {
        el.removeAttribute('data-1000');
        clearInterval(checkEx);
    }
}, 100);
```

---

**Option 3:** Waiting for an element to appear in the code that has an attribute named "data-1000" and only then is it executed.

*If the element you want to edit is loaded by another script and this script is delayed by setting the "datа" values. Then we have to wait for the "data" attribute to appear and then run the script*

```js
    var checkEx = setInterval(function () {
        var el = document.querySelector('[data-1000]');
        if (el) {
            el.removeAttribute('data-1000');
            clearInterval(checkEx);
        }
    }, 100);
```

---

**Example:**
Put this script before skrollr.min.js

```
....

<script>
    document.getElementById('home_bg1').removeAttribute('data-1000');
</script>


<script src="skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script>skrollr.init();</script>

....
```

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere on the internet so I can see it?

Comment: I uploaded the folder to the drive. Can you download and check it?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mpUA2jw4wi-vynIQh2npLGWiiCbxp1B3?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanx. I put the code after skroller.min.js before. That's why it did not work. Now it works. Thank you. :)